# HTML5 embedded in Silverlight Application

Tags: html, silverlight

I am quite new to silverlight and I am seeking advise on embedding external html pages inside silverlight applications.

Can the contents of an external html page be integrated inside a silverlight application ?

How about features like SVG support or Socket.IO which exist in modern browsers ? If the external page is using HTML5 features, can silverlight render/process it correctly ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support for rendering HTML pages in Silverlight. You can however access and manipulate DOM elements from within Silverlight. This allows you to place HTML elemnts on top of a silverlight application and by appropriately adjusting the size and position of these elements you can create the illusion of embedded HTML in simple applications.